# range_sensor_layer marks max sonar range as obstacle?

Tags: ros, gazebo, sonar, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Gazebo to simulate a 4-wheeled differential drive robot. The robot has a forward sonar sensor, so I added a [simulated sonar sensor](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_gazebo_plugins#GazeboRosSonar).

The sonar sensor appears to work; it detects obstacles and the Range messages look correct (e.g. max range value when no obstacles). The visualization in Gazebo also looks correct.

I use the [range_sensor_layer package](http://wiki.ros.org/range_sensor_layer) as a plugin for `costmap_2d`.
My issue is that for some reason, when there is no obstacle and the sonar sensor is at max range, the cost map registers an obstacle.

Below is a screenshot of Gazebo (left), Rviz (top right), and the echo'd Range message (bottom right). I rotated the vehicle in a circle without any obstacles, yet the costmap shows that the robot is surrounded by obstacles.

[image: image description]

Now there's a parameter in `range_sensor_layer` called `clear_on_max_reading`, which will remove obstacles when a reading is max. However I've found that this does more harm than good, because it will clear away actual obstacles by accident.

For example, when it's navigating it runs along the wall and starts creating a wall of obstacles. Eventually it decides to turn, and as the range value maxes out, it clears a whole chunk of actual obstacle. Now there's a hole in the wall, so it tries to navigate towards the hole, and relearns that it's indeed an obstacle. This **repeats forever**. It's both funny and infuriating.

Here are the YAML files I'm using for my costmap:

#### costmap_common_params.yaml

```
map_type: costmap
origin_z: 0.0
z_resolution: 1
z_voxels: 2

obstacle_range: 0.5
raytrace_range: 0.5

footprint: [[-0.21, -0.165], [-0.21, 0.165], [0.21, 0.165], [0.21, -0.165]]
footprint_padding: 0.1

plugins:
- {name: sonar_layer, type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}
- {name: inflater_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

sonar_layer:
  ns: ""
  topics: ["/sonar"]
  no_readings_timeout: 1.0
  clear_threshold: 0.2
  mark_threshold: 0.80
  clear_on_max_reading: false

inflater_layer:
 inflation_radius: 0.3
```

#### local_costmap_params.yaml

```
local_costmap:
   global_frame: odom
   robot_base_frame: base_link
   update_frequency: 20.0
   publish_frequency: 5.0
   width: 10.0
   height: 10.0
   resolution: 0.05
   static_map: false
   rolling_window: true
```

#### global_costmap_params.yaml

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 20
  publish_frequency: 5
  width: 40.0
  height: 40.0
  resolution: 0.05
  origin_x: -20.0
  origin_y: -20.0
  static_map: true
  rolling_window: false
```

In my robot URDF I include the [sonar_sensor macro](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_models/blob/indigo-devel/hector_sensors_description/urdf/sonar_sensor.urdf.xacro) and instantiate my sonar sensor like so:

```
<xacro:sonar_sensor name="sonar" parent="front_mount" ros_topic="sonar" update_rate="10" min_range="0.15" max_range="1.5" field_of_view="${10*PI/180}" ray_count="3" visualize="true">
  <origin xyz="0.0 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</xacro:sonar_sensor>
```

I'm not sure what's going on here. I'd appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238312/range_sensor_layer-marks-max-sonar-range-as-obstacle?/) by [triantatwo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25107/triantatwo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2016-06-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should check to see if your simulated sensors report a value greater than max range, or exactly max range when there is no obstacle within range, and compare that behavior to the code which handles maximum range: https://github.com/DLu/navigation_layers/blob/de3f6706e50c7a37e68b3abfd51a36323c35e726/range_sensor_layer/src/range_sensor_layer.cpp#L224-L235

Ideally, if your sensor is reporting that there is no obstacle within range, there shouldn't be a costmap update for that sensor at all.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [triantatwo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25107/triantatwo/) on 2016-06-28**:
max_range=1.5 and range=1.5 .. judging by that code, it appears that there will be a call `updateCostmap(1.5, false)`. Based off the behavior I'm seeing, it looks like that will update the costmap. I agree, perhaps `processVariableRangeMsg` should just return. I wonder why it doesn't?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-29**:
Might be a bug. You could look through the commit history and look at old pull requests against the package to see where that logic came from. You can also try modifying it to see if you can get the behavior you want, and submit your own pull request if it works.

**Comment by [triantatwo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25107/triantatwo/) on 2016-06-29**:
The solution was straight forward but the trick was knowing where to look. Thanks for your help, ahendrix. I've pushed a patch to my fork for the indigo branch: https://github.com/trianta2/navigation_layers/commit/1c0e918dfac4b6f9263e5d46f1d1565b16033f0f

**Comment by [Syrine](https://answers.ros.org/users/41424/syrine/) on 2019-06-27**:
Hello,
I need your help for something similar can you please check my question?
http://answers.ros.org/question/326995/range_sensor_layer-doesnt-show-obstacles-on-rviz-map/
thanks

**Comment by [amjack](https://answers.ros.org/users/57146/amjack/) on 2022-08-08**:
The sensor could also detect the ground as an obstacle. Change the `p value` in `rpy="0 0 0"` as `rpy="0 -0.5 0"` or something. Then check if the range value has changed. If the range has changed, then it is detecting the ground as an obstacle. This might solve the issue.